# client check if new data is available with httprequest

Tags: java, http, httprequest

I am currently working on a chat project for school where two clients can send messages over a http server. I can already send POST requests with the chat message and the server saves it.

My problem now is that the client needs to know if new chat messages are available. I was trying to do it like this:

```
private void checkChat()
{
    String url = "http://"+serverip+":"+serverport+"/requests";
    while(verbunden==true)
    {
        try
        {
            URL requrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) requrl.openConnection();

            con.setRequestMethod("GET");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
            String inputLine;
            StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
            while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) 
            {
                    response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            gui.writeChat(response.toString());
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }

    }
}
```

but when the method is called the program doesnt work anymore because the server gets flooded I think.

So my question now is: how can I check for new chat messages from the server? I need to use httprequests for that but I dont know how.

Comment: Was it necessary to us HTTP ? Because `Sockets` seems to be a better approach. Anyway, can you debug "_when the method is called the program doesnt work anymore._" since you seems to know what could happen ? How is `checkChat` is called ? EDIT : Owww... `while(true)`. You might want to add a pause in that loop to prevent this to be executed every milliseconds. At the moment the response is receive, the next request is send... and if this runs in the GUI thread, you will never see the new messages by the way.

Comment: @AxelH thanks for your answer! yeah we need to use http for that but I dont know how to do it with sockets either.. and yes I can debug my code but it just loops the whole time so the chatbox isnt updating. I will try to pause the while loop but I still dont know how to check for new data without flooding my server

Comment: Websockets is the way to go for chat related apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are sending this request in a loop :

```
while(verbunden==true)
```

But you didn't write any pause so as soon as a response is receive, the next request is send, this means probably 100 request/second (based on the response time).

Simply add a `Thread.sleep(5000 /*5000ms*/);` in the loop to add a small break.

PS: you could have used two `Socket` to communicate between the server and client, that way the server can inform the client for a new message.

Comment: thank you very much! now it works.. thanks for your help you helped me alot :)